# Behavior of PropTypes.func.isRequired for error handling

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-proptypes

I am new to React and trying to understand an existing project codebase that I need to work on.
In two component classes, I see they define the `onError` property of type `PropTypes.func` as below.

**MyComp.jsx**

```
MyComp.propTypes = {
  //other properties
  onError: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};
```

This property is set at multiple places in the class in the `catch` block as follows.

```
SomerService.someFunc()
.then(() => { // some code  
})
.catch((e) => onError(e));

OR

try {
  //some code
} catch (e) {
  onError(e);
}
```

Based on my little understanding, I was expecting that since the property type is `PropTypes.func` there should be a function named `onError` which basically handles the error or show an error message or something like that. But there is no such method anywhere in the code. So, what exactly does it do? And how are those exceptions/errors handled?

Comment: The component is expecting onError as a props. So when you implement the component somewhere the function might have been passed.  for eg: `<Component onError={() => {}} />`

Comment: That's what, I don't see the function anywhere in the project codebase.

Comment: My react project is a plugin to a portal and looks like the `onError` function is passed by that portal code when my plugin gets called and hence I do not see it in my plugin code. thanks @Yadab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PropTypes are used to validate(to check the type of prop) the props passed to the component.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/prop-types

in your case, the MyComp component accepts the onError prop, whose type is `.func` (a function). and `.isRequired` means that you should send the onError prop to MyComp component whenever you use MyComp.

```
<MyComp onError={(e)=>{/*function to handle error*/}} />
```

Comment: Thanks Pranit, that's what I am saying, there should be a function named `onError` which handles the error. But in the codebase there is none. Where should I check?

Comment: My react project is a plugin to a portal and looks like the `onError` function is passed by that portal code when my plugin gets called and hence I do not see it in my plugin code.